# .setForeground(Color.red); not working\?

Tags: java, text, colors

```
JPanel mygame = new JPanel();
mygame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

mygame.add(new JButton("Start Game"), 

mygame.setForeground(Color.red);

BorderLayout.WEST);
```

This is how I input the code, and I tried diff ways following tutorials but colour of "start game" text will not change. also set background to gray but it stays default color? Can't see what I'm doing wrong, followed tutorial only changed bits for my specific code? help appreciated

Comment: The foreground must be applied to each object that needs it. Applying it to the container will not make all children inherit it. If you want the text to be red on the button, you need to create it first and apply the foreground to the button itself.

Comment: @BackSlash can you give example code please in terms of my one, can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the foreground colour of `JPanel`, change the foreground colour of `JButton`

```
JButton button = new JButton("Start Game")
JPanel mygame = new JPanel();

button.setForeground(Color.red);
mygame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
mygame.add(button);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it should but if it doesn't then you need to include more code in your question so that others can reproduce your problem